# Vundle install vim plugin failed

Tags: vim, vundle

Here is the log when I run PluginInstall in Vim with Vundle.

```
chdir(/usr/share/vim)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "$VIM/vimrc"
Searching for "debian.vim" in "/home/user/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/etc/vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim81,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/etc/vim/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sunxd/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/user/.vim/debian.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/debian.vim"
Searching for "/etc/vim/debian.vim"
Se
```

When I go to .vim/bundle directory, I realized there are indeed a temporary directory corresponding to the plugin that is to be installed but eventually deleted.

When I cd into that repository, I found

```
~/.vim/bundle/vim-gitgutter$ git remote -v
origin  git://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter.git (push)
```

Anything wrong?

Comment: "Anything wrong?" Yes, Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is I have the wrong default git configuration for github.com, which should be by default https, but my configuration was git@github.com